# Ignore emails that match a regexp in Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have an SQL query that returns all companies records ignore the ones with email matching a given pattern using Postgresql (info+random_name@example.com) the plus sign is included as well.

Normal email pattern would be 'random_name@example.com'

My SQL query looks like:

`SELECT * from companies 
  where email !~ E'^(info)+[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+';`

Does the syntax look correct?

## Update:

The following query does match the pattern:

`SELECT * from companies 
  where email ~ E'^(info\+)+[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+';`

Now how to reverse it, as !~ doesn't seem to ignore the matching pattern

## update2:

Correct syntax is indeed the following:

`SELECT * from companies 
  where email ~ E'^info\\+[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape (double escape) the plus sign:

```
E'^(info)\\+[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+'
  here __^^
```

Moreover, there're no need to make a group with `(info)`

```
E'^info\\+[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+'
```

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise:

```
SELECT *
FROM   companies
WHERE  email ~ E'^info\\+[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}';
```

And that does not provide for special characters like `äöü` that are also allowed in domain names.

Answer (score 0):

Test it and tell us?

I think you'll have to change the beginning of your regex for something like:

```
^info\+[A-Z...
```